# Smart way to detecting INSERT/UPDATE SQL query using node-mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, node.js

I'm using Node.js and [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql). I need to detect if a SQL query is an INSERT or UPDATE statement.

Right now I'm running the SQL string through a test regexp, something like the following (I know that regexp can be better, it's just to explain myself):

```js
Pool._isInsertOrUpdate = function(sql){
  return (/^(update|insert)\s+/i).test(sql);
};
```

Is there a smarter way to do that?

Comment: The question here is WHY do you need to know that? Assuming there is a valid reason, you could pass a flag with the sql.

Comment: @DigitalChris I know it may sound weird, but I need to redirect INSERT or UPDATE queries to specific DB pools (read and write) without selecting one with a flag. Something similar to what [this](https://github.com/bdurand/seamless_database_pool) Rails Gem do.

Comment: If you have a read/write master and read-only slaves you might want to look at using some proper middleware rather than using this kind of hack. Had a look at [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com/)? It's a lot better than smashing queries against the MySQL driver.

Comment: If you are trying to do an insert if the record doesn't exist, or update if it does, that's all withing mysql:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the hint. I personally don't like ORMs, but I've looked a bit at Sequelize, since I find it supports read replication in a nice way. If you run a raw query (which is my case), Sequelize [checks if it's a SELECT query with a RegExp](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/aebd144d91848f77cd003908b5a91cff3ad02e94/lib/dialects/sqlite/query.js#L57) and then mark the query as SELECT. Later, query will be redirect to read pool. So basically is almost the same check I've already done, but maybe it's faster checking for SELECTs instead of UPDATE/INSERT.

Comment: If you don't like ORMs you've probably been using the wrong ones. Sequelize is pretty good, it does its job without forcing you to re-write your entire app, and gets out of the way when it's no longer helping. It's also really good at making queries easier to write as it handles some of the more complicated escaping you may need to deal with.